# How to mount a shared region under /dev/shmem in QNX?

Tags: qnx, qnx-neutrino

I am new to QNX Neutrino , I have a Virtual Machine with a vdev shmem configuration.
I ran the command in the VM shmem-guest 0xAddressnumber interruptNumber , however in the host i can see the area is created by the guest correctly.
how can make the host and guest communicate through that shmem area?
for example shall i mount the area first in the host? if so , how can i mount it.